# Change layout login

Tags: php, magento

How can I change the layout of the login page? No changes I make in the templates works. I even deleted all the template files to see if anything changed, but still appears login. My cache is disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're unable to locate a `phtml` file it's best to turn on template hints.

1. Disable cache
2. In the backend go to `System` > `Configuration` > `Developer` and fill out your IP
3. Change the scope to website level with the top left dropdown
4. Turn on `Template Path Hints` under `Debug`

In the frontend refresh the page and the path to the login template should be visible.

PS. Credits to `Sander Mangel`

Comment: Thanks for your help. You saved my life.

Answer (score 0):

You need create a custom `local.xml` file in your theme's **layout** directory or edit `customer.xml`(*same directory*)  file. You may try like this.

`app/design/frontend/theme-package/theme-name/layout/local.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <customer_account_login>
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <!-- Mage_Customer -->
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
  </customer_account_login>
</layout>
```

Comment: I edited, but does not alter the fact. I even deleted all customer layout files, but still he walks renders the old layout.